# Invalid carrier specified - Cannot add tracking to shipment

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, api, soap

I'm trying to **add tracking to orders via the SOAP (V1) interface using the `sales_order_shipment.addTrack` method** - but as the title suggests I'm **getting the following error: `Invalid carrier specified`**

The first thing I tried was to use the `custom` carrier code as such:

```
'shipmentIncrementId' => $shipmentIncrementId,
'carrier' => 'custom',
'title' => 'My courier',
'trackNumber' => $tracking
```

(Note that both `$shipmentIncrementId` and `$tracking` are correct.)

This produced the aforementioned error.

So I decided to make my own module adding a custom carrier, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/). Most importantly, I've implemented `isTrackingAvailable()` and made it return `true`.

Now, interestingly, if I make the call to `sales_order_shipment.getCarriers` my custom carrier is there, so it should be available! However, when I again make the `sales_order_shipment.addTrack` call with the following details:

```
'shipmentIncrementId' => $shipmentIncrementId,
'carrier' => 'name_of_module',
'title' => 'Custom Carrier',
'trackNumber' => $tracking
```

Where `name_of_module` is obviously the correct name of the module, returned by `getCarriers` and this time I've matched the title to the one defined in the module (`Custom Carrier`).

With this, I still get the same error of `Invalid carrier specified`! Surely if `getCarriers` returns this carrier for an order it shouldn't be invalid?

The only place on the web that attempts to document this error is [here](https://cartrover.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CART/Invalid+carrier+specified+-+Magento), as described above I have followed the suggested steps according to that link.

Could anyone point me to where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

**P.S.** If it makes any difference, I'm trying to avoid adding a new module for every single carrier we use, I'd like to be able to pass through the correct title of the carrier through SOAP and add any tracking number (we don't use any of the predefined carriers in Magento).

---

**Edit**

The following is the code that calls the API:

```
$this->magentoAPI->request(
    'sales_order_shipment.addTrack',
        [
            'shipmentIncrementId' => $shipmentIncrementId,
            'carrier' => 'fesp_fixstupidcarriers',
            'title' => 'Custom Carrier',
            'trackNumber' => $tracking,
        ]
);
```

This uses my custom function, which in turn runs `call_user_func_array([$client, 'call'], $arguments);`

`$arguments` comes out as the following array:

```
[
    'whatever-the-session-id-is',
    'sales_order_shipment.addTrack',
    '100002290',
    'fesp_fixstupidcarriers',
    'Custom Carrier',
    '9348278247008183'
];
```

I'm showing actual data this time, that's a real `shipmentIncrementId`, the actual carrier code, and the real tracking number.

This function works for all other calls of the API I've tried (about a dozen).

Comment: What happens if you call the API without the array keys ? Just by giving an array of values in the right order ?

Comment: The same, only shipmentIncrementId posted. I also tried mocking out my function and doing it directly with and without keys, no change in results either way.

Comment: Well i'm out of ideas here. Pretty sure you'll have to go in hardcode debugging mode. Try to check that good article: http://alanstorm.com/debugging_magento_api_method_calls

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I'll give you the bounty seeing how helpful you were :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what can cause this but I'm going to give you the steps to debug the problem.

### The error

The error you're getting:

> Invalid carrier specified.

Comes from the following file: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php` in the `addTrack()` method:

```
public function addTrack($shipmentIncrementId, $carrier, $title, $trackNumber)
{
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipmentIncrementId);

    /* @var $shipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment */

    if (!$shipment->getId()) {
        $this->_fault('not_exists');
    }

    $carriers = $this->_getCarriers($shipment);

    if (!isset($carriers[$carrier])) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid carrier specified.'));
    }

    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                ->setNumber($trackNumber)
                ->setCarrierCode($carrier)
                ->setTitle($title);

    $shipment->addTrack($track);

    try {
        $shipment->save();
        $track->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $track->getId();
}
```

As you can see this method does the following:

- load the shipment
- get the carriers for the shipment
- check if the carrier provided is allowed
- create the tracking
- add the tracking to the shipment
- save both tracking and shipment

### Investigating

As you can see, the list of allowed carriers is retrieved via a protected method in that same class `_getCarriers` :

```
protected function _getCarriers($object)
{
    $carriers = array();
    $carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers(
        $object->getStoreId()
    );

    $carriers['custom'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Value');
    foreach ($carrierInstances as $code => $carrier) {
        if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
            $carriers[$code] = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
        }
    }

    return $carriers;
}
```

Here how I would start the debugging process.

1. Add the following line at the beggining of the `addTrack()` method:

   ```
   Mage::log("---".$carrier."---");
   ```
2. Then add the following line before `return $carriers;` in the `_getCarriers()` method:

   ```
   Mage::log($carriers);
   ```
3. Call your `sales_order_shipment.addTrack` and check your `var/log/system.log` for the result

### Case 1: your carrier code is not a key of the carriers array

Two possibilities here:

- **Your carrier is not enabled / allowed for the specified store.** Indeed the following code retrieves the list of all carriers but it filters them by store id. Double check the carrier configuration using the scope dropdown:

  ```
  $carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers(
      $object->getStoreId()
  );
  ```
- **Your carrier does not have tracking available.** I guess you already did check that but open the model that corresponds to the carrier and check what the `isTrackingAvailable()` method returns. If such method is not declared in the carrier model, that means it returns false and thus tracking is not available for this carrier.

### Case 2: your carrier code is a key of the carrier array

First, **ensure that there's no whitespaces around your carrier code.** That's the reason why I added the `---` before and after the carrier code in the debugging code.

You can further investigate the differences by replacing:

```
    if (!isset($carriers[$carrier])) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid carrier specified.'));
    }
```

By:

```
foreach ($carriers as $key => $value) {
    Mage::log("checking key: ".$key."---");
    Mage::log("provided key: ".$carrier."---");
}
if (!isset($carriers[$carrier])) {
    $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid carrier specified.'));
}
```

If you're in this case, it's pretty much a typo IMO.

Comment: Thank you for this, very useful information. I'll investigate and get back to you

Comment: I'm finally able to come back to this issue, I've added the `Mage::log()` lines in the relevant places, and this is what I get:

`Missing argument 2 for Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api::addTrack(), called in /home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php on line 294 and defined/home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php` (Same for argument 3 and 4)

Comment: I posted that prematurely, that error is followed by these: 

`Undefined variable: carrier/home/account/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php`
Which I guess is caused by the above error, i.e. not getting the arguments.

Then we get to the `Mage::log()` entries, in `addTrack()` it just returns `------` obviously because `$carrier` is undefined, then it correctly prints out the array of carriers for the `_getCarriers()` function.

Comment: Considering the above, I have just added `Mage::log(func_get_args());` to the top of `addTrack()` to see what it's actually getting, and as the errors suggest it's only getting the `shipmentIncrementId`, any ideas why this would be?

Comment: @SworrubWehttam very interesting. Could you post the exact code that calls the addTrack API in your question please ?

Comment: Done :) check out the edit

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a bad hack job, but for me the API returned the same array of available carriers as the dropdown menu in admin does.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/salesOrderShipment.html

This returned:
array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["key"]=> string(6) 
/"custom" ["value"]=> string(13) "Mukailtu arvo" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2) { ["key"]=> string(3) 
"dhl" ["value"]=> string(3) "DHL" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#45 (2) { ["key"]=> string(5) 
"fedex" ["value"]=> string(15) "Federal Express" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#32 (2) { ["key"]=> string(3) 
"ups" ["value"]=> string(21) "United Parcel Service" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) 
"usps" ["value"]=> string(28) "United States Postal Service" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#36 (2) { ["key"]=> string(6) 
"dhlint" ["value"]=> string(3) "DHL" } } int(5)

I looked at the code that my carrier is using to save it's tracking code with it's own carrier code (that's not working via API) and it was using this code in Abstract.php

```
    $track->setNumber($trackingCode)
            ->setCarrierCode($shipment->getShippinglabelsType())
            ->setTitle($shipment->getShippinglabelsTypeName());
```

I commented out the check for checking invalid carrier (hack job...)
and changed the way carrier & title are decided to match our carrier:

```
   // if (!isset($carriers[$carrier])) {
    //    $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid carrier specified.'));
    //}

    $carrier = $shipment->getShippinglabelsType();
    $title = $shipment->getShippinglabelsTypeName();

    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                ->setNumber($trackNumber)
                ->setCarrierCode($carrier)
                ->setTitle($title);
```

Now I can just send an tracking number via API without invalid carrier errors. It would be worth the extra effort to restore the invalid carrier method check and just integrate the shippinglabel code within the error check, but this is a quick way to get things working.